# In Terraform, how can I execute a user_data Powershell script with elevated privileges?

Tags: powershell, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am creating a windows EC2 instance with Terraform and trying to install Chocolatley using user_data init script. But powershell script fails with access denied

**ec2_tableau.tf**

```
resource "aws_instance" "tableau_instance" {
  ami                         = data.aws_ami.windowsbase.id
  for_each                    = var.tableau_instances
  subnet_id                   = each.value
  instance_type               = var.tableau_instance_type
  key_name                    = var.key_pair_name
  vpc_security_group_ids      = BLABLABLA
  user_data                   = data.template_file.userdata_tableau.rendered
  iam_instance_profile        = aws_iam_instance_profile.tableau_iam_profile.name
  associate_public_ip_address = false

  root_block_device {
    volume_type = "gp2"
    volume_size = var.tableau_root_device_size
  }

}
```

**ec2_tableau_userdata.tf**

```
data "template_file" "userdata_tableau" {
  vars = {
    #puppet_server = var.puppet_server
    proxy_url     = var.proxy_url
  }

  template = <<EOF
<powershell>
netsh winhttp set proxy $${proxy_url}

## Install Chocolatey ##
$env:chocolateyProxyLocation = 'http://$${proxy_url}'
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process -Force ; 
[System.Net.WebRequest]::DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultCredentials; iex ((New-Object Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" 

## Update path for Chocolatey
BLABLABLA
start-service ShellHWDetection
</powershell>
EOF
}
```

Powershell runs in new EC2 instance but when I get to this line

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process -Force;
```

Temp .ps1 file runs, runs ok but fails in that line with **"access denied"**.
The reason is that temp .ps1 script is executed with no elevated privileges

So my question is:

**In Terraform, how can I execute a user_data Powershell script with elevated privileges?**